# Converting Float to Int Gives wrong result

Tags: swift, floating-accuracy

I was solving a problem and noticed that conversion of Float value to Int gives wrong result. Below is peice of code which involves the conversion

```
while(height >= 0.0){
        height = (v * t) - (0.5*g*t*t)
        if(height >= maxHeight) {
            d_time = t
            maxHeight = height
            print(d_time)
        }
        t += 0.1
    }
    let time = d_time * 10.0
    print(d_time, Int(time)) // it prints 2.4, 23
    return time
```

However if I tried converting literals it works correct. 
For example

```
let time = 2.4 * 10.0
print(time) // prints 24 as expected.
```

I tried to figure out the issue but not able to get it. 
Please help in understanding this behavior.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `print(d_time.debugDescription)` to your code and you'll see the problem.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. Got the point.